# StackOverflowError -java

Tags: java, graph, depth-first-search, stack-overflow

I am writing a code to run DFS on a graph however these graphs are huge.  I am getting a stack overflow error on DFS visit however other people were able to run DFS visit without any problems.  Is there any reason why I would be getting a StackOverFlow error?  I tried allocating more memory (I have 16gb RAM) however it caps me at 1gb ram.

```
public void DFSVisit(Graph <String, String> graph, String current, int [] data, StackObject [] finish, boolean complicated){
    //data stores the time
    data[9]++;
    graph.setAnnotation(current, "time", data[9]);
    graph.setAnnotation(current, "color", "gray");
    Iterator <ArrayList<String>> itr = graph.outAdjacentVertices(current);
    ArrayList <String> currentlist = null;
    String adjacent;
    while(itr.hasNext()){
        currentlist = itr.next();
        adjacent = currentlist.get(1);
            if(graph.getAnnotation(adjacent, "color").equals("white")){
                graph.setAnnotation(adjacent, "parent", current);
                DFSVisit(graph, adjacent, data, finish, complicated);
            }
    }
    graph.setAnnotation(current, "color", "black");
    data[9]++;
    graph.setAnnotation(current, "done", data[9]);
    finish[0].done.push(current);
    //System.out.println(current);
}
```

Comment: If the search space is infinite every system running your code will get this exception.

Comment: You have to mark the current node as visited so you do not come back to it from the adjacent list of vertices. Imagine a simple graph with two vertices and an edge joining them. Both vertices adjacent list will contain each other and your algorithm will just visit them over and over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched over to working on my laptop and it worked immediately.  Apparently the problem was  me using a 32 bit Eclipse instead of a 64 bit Eclipse.  I didn't even realize I was using a 32 bit on my desktop.

Answer (score 1):

Allocating memory will not help.
You call DFSVisit inside same method and no return condition defined for the method hence it will throw stackoverflow error.

Answer (score 1):

You have to stop recursive calls on some point..with some condition..otherwise it will be endless calls and will throw stack-overflow error.

Answer (score 0):

please note that the space complexity of the DFS is **O(b.m)** where m is depth of the search space and b is the maximum branching factor, so if m is infinite, you may never be able to solve the problem with an inappropriate implementation.

To find a better example, look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6414601/whats-the-best-way-to-perform-dfs-on-a-very-large-tree) question on  SO.